# Mysql Trigger Update after Update error #1064

Tags: mysql

Comando SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER seq_uci_to_procedimento 
AFTER UPDATE ON seq_uci 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE `pre_procedimento`
    SET  `pre_num_uci` = (CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id))
    WHERE
    `pre_id` = (NEW.seq_id_procedimento)
END
```

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

> **Error Translation:** you have an error in your sql syntax near 'TABLE `pre_procedimento`'

## 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'TABLE `pre_procedimento`

```
SET  `pre_num_uci` = (CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id))
```

' na linha 5

Comment: Please translate the error 1064 to english? And make sure you ask your question in english

Comment: You have a syntaxe error on your SQL: 'TABLE pre_procedimento SET `Spre_num_uci` = (CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id))' on line 5

Comment: I Try too:

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `seq_uci_to_procedimento` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `seq_uci` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE `pre_procedimento`
    SET  pre_num_uci = CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id)
    WHERE
    pre_id = NEW.seq_id_procedimento
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com or https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove "TABLE" from your statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER seq_uci_to_procedimento 
AFTER UPDATE ON seq_uci 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `pre_procedimento`
    SET  `pre_num_uci` = (CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id))
    WHERE
    `pre_id` = (NEW.seq_id_procedimento)
END
```

Check [here for how to write UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statements

Answer (score 1):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER seq_uci_to_procedimento AFTER UPDATE ON seq_uci FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE  pre_procedimento 
SET  pre_num_uci = (CONCAT_WS(NEW.ano, NEW.id)) 
WHERE  pre_id = (NEW.seq_id_procedimento) ;
END $$
delimiter ;
```